# Change Background-Color of div element Cross Fade in a Loop

Tags: javascript, css, background-color, fade

I want to change the background color of a div element from black to red to blue via crossfade , but right now have no idea how to do it. I tried doing it with images, but putting an image as background and change via fade effect  makes it heavy. Is there any way to do it via CSS or Javascript? Please Help.

Comment: Change the background color of a div element from black to red to blue via crossfade [jsfiddle.netTytSZ](http://jsfiddle.net/TytSZ/). I tried doing it with images, but putting an image as background and change via fade effect makes it heavy [jsfiddle.net/562am](http://jsfiddle.net/562am/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS:

```css
.fadechange {
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background: black;
    animation: fading 4s infinite;
   -webkit-animation: fading 4s infinite;
}

@keyframes fading {
    0%   { background: black; }
    33%  { background: red; }
    66%  { background: blue; }
    100% { background: black; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fading {
    0%   { background: black; }
    33%  { background: red; }
    66%  { background: blue; }
    100% { background: black; }
}
```

According to w3schools this must work in IE(10+), Opera, Chrome, Safari and Firefox. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TytSZ/1/)

Comment: Thank You Maria for this working solution. Its working great. I had few queries about the code above. How is the time lapse managed? And what is the compatibility of keyframes with old browsers, as i read it is not compatible below IE9?

Comment: These means that the full animation lasts for 4 seconds. The animation starts at 0% and ends at 100%, so it will be red after 1.33s, blue at 2.66 and black again at 4s. This repeates infinitely.

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out after some time. Its working great, but after sometime, it lags and slows down. It doesn't sync like in here [jsfiddle.net/NFyPX](http://jsfiddle.net/NFyPX/).